# debugging a python file in vs code with input text file

Tags: json, python-3.x, file-io, text-files, vscode-debugger

Need help regarding how to use a text file while debugging in visual studio code (i.e.file.py < input.txt)

this the launch.json file , how give my input text file at time of debugging in visual Studio code

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/covering_segments.py",
            "console": "externalTerminal",
            
            
        }    
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to do the same thing and the adding the input as arg worked for me. For your case:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/covering_segments.py",
            "console": "externalTerminal",
            "args": [
                "<",
                "${workspaceFolder}/input.txt",
            ]
        }    
    ]
}
```