# Visual Studio Code Debug Python Redirecting Input from Text File in Virtual Environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, debugging

I am following the code mentioned in [debugging a python file in vs code with input text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65165574/debugging-a-python-file-in-vs-code-with-input-text-file).
To get my error:

1. Create a new virtual pip virtual environment.
2. Create a new folder called `project`.
3. Inside `project`, create simple "sort two numbers" python file `hello.py`:

```
line = input()
a,b = line.split()
a = int(a)
b = int(b)
if a <= b:
    print(a)
    print(b)
else:
    print(b)
    print(a)
```

(If possible, I prefer answers that do not modify this .py file because I am  actually working on problems like the ones in kattis. The code passes the test of https://open.kattis.com/problems/sorttwonumbers .)
As my goal is to redirect input from a text file, I create the following `input.txt` also in `project`:

```
987 23
```

(This input.txt is legitimate: use Pycharm to redirect input for example will make the `hello.py` run correctly.)
By setting the python interpreter to be the virtual environment, we can see that `hello.py` runs in the virtual environment if the user gives numbers in the command line because green environment name shows up in the command line.

4. Create folder `.vscode` in `project`, in which we create `launch.json`. Here are my two attempts. The first attempt quotes https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_redirect-inputoutput-tofrom-the-debug-target:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "PYTHON REDIRECT INPUT",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\hello",
            "console": "externalTerminal",
            "args": ["<","${workspaceFolder}\\input.txt"],
        }    
    ]
}
```

Whether in program I use `hello` or `hello.py`, whether in console I use `externalTerminal` or `integratedTerminal`, it won't respond when I click on run on the left side menu of visual studio code. In the end, it always gives:

[image]

My second attempt deletes the `"<"` symbol in the args:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "PYTHON REDIRECT INPUT",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\hello.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": ["${workspaceFolder}\\input.txt"],
        }    
    ]
}
```

I have also changed the external terminal to "integratedTerminal", use `hello.py` instead of `hello`, and deleted "<" in args. Consequently, there is no longer any error message showing up when running the code and no more error windows popping up. The code runs whiling stopping at all stopping points, if I manually give the right inputs. That is, the `input.txt` does not participate in the debugging. So the problem remain unresolved.

Comment: one issue is that you should probably be using hellp.py instead of hello in the `program` field- at least- I needed to when running with the integrated terminal.

Comment: I have updated the post. `hello.py` or `hello` yields exactly the same result.

Comment: The problem is that this method input() requires the content you input instead of parameters passed by args.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT uhh no? input will read from the standard input stream. the file redirect makes the file be used for the standard input stream. It works fine when run in the integrated terminal for me.

Comment: @user It's strange, even if I use `sys.args()` to ensure that `987 23` can be passed correctly, I still cannot successfully run the code in the article.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT args are separate from the input stream. redirection of a file into the standard input stream of a program of course will not show up in `sys.args()`.

Comment: I have updated the post. I use this code because it runs on kattis. The input is legitamate because I have checked this input text file on say PyCharm.

Comment: any difference if you change `"console": "externalTerminal"` to `"console": "integratedTerminal"`?

Comment: No change at all. Same "time out waiting error".

Comment: I created a simple new project in WSL on Windows to recreate your example. To get it to work, I only had to change "externalTerminal" to "integratedTerminal"

Please note that this my be environment specific, but the run configuration otherwise works. Even breakpoints work as expected.

Comment: @nicc777 the same for me. It works fine with integratedTerminal. That's why I asked. I wonder if something with externalTerminal here is bugged, because the externalTerminal won't even start up for me.

Comment: I have drastically updated the post. Changing the terminal + changing .py + removing the "<" symbol in args will make my debugging show no more error and stop at where it should. However, I will need to manually give inputs and the `input.txt` is not used by visual studio code.

Comment: I include both attempts now. The problem is unresolved.

Comment: I believe your problem is environment specific, as it definitely works otherwise. This is not a VSCode problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you said you would prefer not to modify your existing code. But wouldn't that be a better approach if the correct tool were available that would work in all environments, well at least your environment?

Python provides a function [`fileinput.input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html?highlight=input#fileinput.input) that when called with no arguments will return an instance of class `fileinput.FileInput`, which has a `readline` method that will return lines of input from *stdin* (which can be the console or a redirected file), **or it will iterate over the lines of all files listed in sys.argv[1:], which is what you would want to do.** The changes to your code are minimal:

```py
import fileinput

with fileinput.input() as file:
    line = file.readline() # just read a single line

a,b = line.split()
a = int(a)
b = int(b)
if a <= b:
    print(a)
    print(b)
else:
    print(b)
    print(a)
```

If the above code is in a file **test.py**, then you could run it with no arguments and then you would need to specify your input from the console. But you could also pass a single argument to **test.py**, a path to the file containing your input, and then the same code will read from that file instead of from the console. Or, finally, instead of passing the file path as an argument, **you just arrange to have the file redirected as *stdin***.

**Would this work for you in your environment?**

Comment: Yes. This works for me and for kattis. Thank you.